# Fody Async MethodDecorator to Handle Exceptions

Tags: c#, asynchronous, il, fody

I am trying to use Fody to wrap all exceptions thrown from a method with a common exception format.

So I have added the required interface declaration and class implementation that looks like this :

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[module: MethodDecorator]

public interface IMethodDecorator
{
  void Init(object instance, MethodBase method, object[] args);
  void OnEntry();
  void OnExit();
  void OnException(Exception exception);
  void OnTaskContinuation(Task t);
}


[AttributeUsage(
    AttributeTargets.Module |
    AttributeTargets.Method |
    AttributeTargets.Assembly |
    AttributeTargets.Constructor, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class MethodDecorator : Attribute, IMethodDecorator
{
  public virtual void Init(object instance, MethodBase method, object[] args) { }

  public void OnEntry()
  {
    Debug.WriteLine("base on entry");
  }

  public virtual void OnException(Exception exception)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine("base on exception");
  }

  public void OnExit()
  {
    Debug.WriteLine("base on exit");
  }

  public void OnTaskContinuation(Task t)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine("base on continue");
  }
}
```

And the domain implementation that looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;

namespace CC.Spikes.AOP.Fody
{
  public class FodyError : MethodDecorator
  {
    public string TranslationKey { get; set; }
    public Type ExceptionType { get; set; }

    public override void Init(object instance, MethodBase method, object[] args)
    {
      SetProperties(method);
    }

    private void SetProperties(MethodBase method)
    {
      var attribute = method.CustomAttributes.First(n => n.AttributeType.Name == nameof(FodyError));
      var translation = attribute
        .NamedArguments
        .First(n => n.MemberName == nameof(TranslationKey))
        .TypedValue
        .Value
          as string;

      var exceptionType = attribute
        .NamedArguments
        .First(n => n.MemberName == nameof(ExceptionType))
        .TypedValue
        .Value
          as Type;


      TranslationKey = translation;
      ExceptionType = exceptionType;
    }

    public override void OnException(Exception exception)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine("entering fody error exception");
      if (exception.GetType() != ExceptionType)
      {
        Debug.WriteLine("rethrowing fody error exception");
        //rethrow without losing stacktrace
        ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(exception).Throw();
      }

      Debug.WriteLine("creating new fody error exception");
      throw new FodyDangerException(TranslationKey, exception);

    }
  }

  public class FodyDangerException : Exception
  {
    public string CallState { get; set; }
    public FodyDangerException(string message, Exception error) : base(message, error)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

This works fine for synchronous code. But for asynchronous code the exception handler is skipped, even though all the other IMethodDecorator are executed (like `OnExit`, and `OnTaskContinuation`).

For example, looking at the following test class :

```
public class FodyTestStub
{ 

  [FodyError(ExceptionType = typeof(NullReferenceException), TranslationKey = "EN_WHATEVER")]
  public async Task ShouldGetErrorAsync()
  {
    await Task.Delay(200);
    throw new NullReferenceException();
  }

  public async Task ShouldGetErrorAsync2()
  {
    await Task.Delay(200);
    throw new NullReferenceException();
  }
}
```

I see that `ShouldGetErrorAsync` produces the following IL code :

```
// CC.Spikes.AOP.Fody.FodyTestStub
[FodyError(ExceptionType = typeof(NullReferenceException), TranslationKey = "EN_WHATEVER"), DebuggerStepThrough, AsyncStateMachine(typeof(FodyTestStub.<ShouldGetErrorAsync>d__3))]
public Task ShouldGetErrorAsync()
{
    MethodBase methodFromHandle = MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(methodof(FodyTestStub.ShouldGetErrorAsync()).MethodHandle, typeof(FodyTestStub).TypeHandle);
    FodyError fodyError = (FodyError)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(FodyError));
    object[] args = new object[0];
    fodyError.Init(this, methodFromHandle, args);
    fodyError.OnEntry();
    Task task;
    try
    {
        FodyTestStub.<ShouldGetErrorAsync>d__3 <ShouldGetErrorAsync>d__ = new FodyTestStub.<ShouldGetErrorAsync>d__3();
        <ShouldGetErrorAsync>d__.<>4__this = this;
        <ShouldGetErrorAsync>d__.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Create();
        <ShouldGetErrorAsync>d__.<>1__state = -1;
        AsyncTaskMethodBuilder <>t__builder = <ShouldGetErrorAsync>d__.<>t__builder;
        <>t__builder.Start<FodyTestStub.<ShouldGetErrorAsync>d__3>(ref <ShouldGetErrorAsync>d__);
        task = <ShouldGetErrorAsync>d__.<>t__builder.Task;
        fodyError.OnExit();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        fodyError.OnException(exception);
        throw;
    }
    return task;
}
```

And `ShouldGetErrorAsync2` generates :

```
    // CC.Spikes.AOP.Fody.FodyTestStub
[DebuggerStepThrough, AsyncStateMachine(typeof(FodyTestStub.<ShouldGetErrorAsync2>d__4))]
public Task ShouldGetErrorAsync2()
{
    FodyTestStub.<ShouldGetErrorAsync2>d__4 <ShouldGetErrorAsync2>d__ = new FodyTestStub.<ShouldGetErrorAsync2>d__4();
    <ShouldGetErrorAsync2>d__.<>4__this = this;
    <ShouldGetErrorAsync2>d__.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Create();
    <ShouldGetErrorAsync2>d__.<>1__state = -1;
    AsyncTaskMethodBuilder <>t__builder = <ShouldGetErrorAsync2>d__.<>t__builder;
    <>t__builder.Start<FodyTestStub.<ShouldGetErrorAsync2>d__4>(ref <ShouldGetErrorAsync2>d__);
    return <ShouldGetErrorAsync2>d__.<>t__builder.Task;
}
```

If I call `ShouldGetErrorAsync`, Fody is intercepting the call, and wrapping the method body in a try catch. But if the method is async, it never hits the catch statement even though the `fodyError.OnTaskContinuation(task)` and `fodyError.OnExit()` are still called.

On the other hand, `ShouldGetErrorAsync` will handle the error just fine, even though there is no error handling block in the IL.

My question is, how should Fody be generating the IL to properly inject the error block and make it so async errors are intercepted?

[Here is a repo with tests that reproduces the issue](https://github.com/swestner/CC.Spike.AOP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only placing the try-catch around the content of the 'kick-off' method, this will only protect you up to the point where it first needs to reschedule (the 'kick-off' method will end when the async method first needs to reschedule and so will not be on the stack when the async method resumes).

You should look at modifying the method implementing `IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()` on the state machine instead. In particular, look for the call to `SetException(Exception)` on the async method builder (`AsyncVoidMethodBuilder`, `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder` or `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<TResult>`) and wrap the exception just before passing it in.

Comment: This is technically correct, but was difficult to implement. In the end I switched libraries to https://github.com/vescon/MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody. This handles the async issues and I found the project to be easier to work with and modify.

Answer (score 1):

`await` sure makes asynchronous methods look simple, doesn't it? :) You just found a leak in that abstraction - the method usually returns as soon as the first `await` is found, and your exception helper has no way to intercept any later exceptions.

What you need to do is implement both the `OnException`, and handle the return value from the method. When the method returns, and the task isn't completed, you need to wind up an error continuation on the task, which needs to handle exceptions the way you want them to be handled. The Fody guys thought of that - that's what the `OnTaskContinuation` is for. You need to check the `Task.Exception` to see if there's an exception lurking in the task, and handle it however you need to.

I think this will only work if you want to rethrow the exception while doing logging or something - it does not allow you to replace the exception with something different. You should test that :)

Comment: Unfortunately you are correct, the error can only be reported on and not rehandled.